# Error when autostarting Python3 script with systemd

Tags: python-3.x, systemd

So far I have been running a Python3 script with screen. However this gets annoying when I restart my RPI. Therefore I wI created this systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=BME680_Wohnzimmer
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /srv/scripts/bsec_bme680_linux/bsec_bme680.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When requesting the status I get:

```
    ● bme680_wohnzimmer.service - BME680_Wohnzimmer
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bme680_wohnzimmer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-08-12 11:59:47 UTC; 2h 45min ago
  Process: 1640 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /srv/scripts/bsec_bme680_linux/bsec_bme680.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1640 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:   File "/srv/scripts/bsec_bme680_linux/bsec_bme680.py", line 7, in <module>
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:     proc = subprocess.Popen(['./bsec_bme680'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:     restore_signals, start_new_session)
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]:     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi python3[1640]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './bsec_bme680'
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bme680_wohnzimmer.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bme680_wohnzimmer.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 12 11:59:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bme680_wohnzimmer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The failing line is:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./bsec_bme680'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When running this via "sudo python3 bsec_bme680.py everything is fine..Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> python3[1640]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   './bsec_bme680'

If using relative paths, you have to set (`systemd.exit(5)`):

> ```
>    WorkingDirectory=
>        Takes a directory path relative to the service's root directory specified by RootDirectory=, or the special value "~". Sets the working directory for executed processes. If set to "~", the home
>        directory of the user specified in User= is used. If not set, defaults to the root directory when systemd is running as a system instance and the respective user's home directory if run as user.
>        If the setting is prefixed with the "-" character, a missing working directory is not considered fatal. If RootDirectory=/RootImage= is not set, then WorkingDirectory= is relative to the root of
>        the system running the service manager. Note that setting this parameter might result in additional dependencies to be added to the unit (see above).
> ```

Better solution: Use absolute Paths in your service.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this out tonight! Just out of interest: Why would an absolute path ever be better?